# Spring @cacheable how to refresh cache 12am?

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-cache, spring-scheduled

I would like to refresh the cache everyday 12am or the cache expired at 12am. I had check the available methods in `net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration`, but these methods i.e. `timeToIdleSeconds`, `timeToLiveSeconds` seem like not what I want. May I know how to achieve this?

Edit 1:

Here is how I use @Cacheable.

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "cacheName")
public Object retrieveConfigurations() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Take a look at spring scheduling, you can clear cache using this. Refer  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@Scheduled`:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "<cron expression>")
@CacheEvict(value = "<cache name>")
public void clearCache() {      
}
```